# Convergence compared to genetic distance

Tags: genetics, evolution

Is there an information (preferably in the form of a chart, though anything will do) comparing convergent evolution to how closely related the 2 species are on the tree of life.
My searches for anything touching on this subject have returned nothing

Context: 
I was having a discussion with a friend on how similar we should expect alien life to be to earth. The topic of high levels of convergence on earth being indicative of convergence between life on Earth and life with a seperate origin on another planet came up. However it appears to me that convergence tends to happen a lot more in more closely related species, but I have no solid data for or against this idea. For example I don't think any plantae have developed any significant ability to move, like animalia have, which I find surprising as it is a very broad ability.

Please note my knowledge of biology is only on a general level.

Comment: `convergent evolution` is a concept. It does not take a value. It is not a variable to be plotted. What variable do you have in mind?

Comment: I know it's unlikely I'll get a chart as convergence is qualitative rather than quantitative. If there is a way that it is measured even in a more fuzzy way, a chart would be great but it's not required.

Comment: Technically, it is not qualitative either. It is not not numerical, ordinal, nominal, boolean or whatever. It is a concept. The question of how to measure depend upon what you want to measure and I am afraid we cannot define that for you. Note that among examples of distantly related species that undergo convergence evolution, there are bats and birds, flying squirrel and flying lizards, Euphorbia and Astrophytum, vertebrates and insect legs, dolphins and ichthyosaurs.

Comment: Among highly related lineages, the concept of convergent evolution is a bit hard to define though. How differentiated two phenotype must be so as to consider that two lineages have undergone convergence evolution if their phenotype converges. Note that we would rarely be able to detect such small deviations anyway. Another semantic issue is that the concept of convergence evolution can be defined for both phenotypic trait and genetic sequence. I here assumed you were talking about phenotypic trait.